# Ho to use XOM on android, parse problems

Tags: android, xml, sax

I use XOM to create XML on android, it's worked, but when I have tried to parse some xml with XOM's Builder I have an error:

```
11-28 22:00:11.290: I/dalvikvm(26548): Could not find method org.apache.xerces.impl.Version.getVersion, referenced from method nu.xom.Builder.<clinit>
11-28 22:00:11.290: W/dalvikvm(26548): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5819: Lorg/apache/xerces/impl/Version;.getVersion ()Ljava/lang/String;
11-28 22:00:11.290: D/dalvikvm(26548): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000f
11-28 22:00:11.295: W/dalvikvm(26548): Unable to resolve superclass of Lnu/xom/XML1_0Parser; (921)
11-28 22:00:11.295: W/dalvikvm(26548): Link of class 'Lnu/xom/XML1_0Parser;' failed
11-28 22:00:11.295: E/dalvikvm(26548): Could not find class 'nu.xom.XML1_0Parser', referenced from method nu.xom.Builder.findParser
11-28 22:00:11.295: W/dalvikvm(26548): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 699 (Lnu/xom/XML1_0Parser;) in Lnu/xom/Builder;
11-28 22:00:11.295: D/dalvikvm(26548): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
11-28 22:00:11.300: W/dalvikvm(26548): Unable to resolve superclass of Lnu/xom/XML1_0Parser; (921)
11-28 22:00:11.300: W/dalvikvm(26548): Link of class 'Lnu/xom/XML1_0Parser;' failed
11-28 22:00:11.300: D/dalvikvm(26548): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x1160 at 0x02 in Lnu/xom/Builder;.findParser
11-28 22:00:11.300: W/dalvikvm(26548): Unable to resolve superclass of Lnu/xom/JDK15XML1_0Parser; (461)
11-28 22:00:11.300: W/dalvikvm(26548): Link of class 'Lnu/xom/JDK15XML1_0Parser;' failed
11-28 22:00:11.325: D/dalvikvm(26548): GC_CONCURRENT freed 377K, 4% free 11719K/12167K, paused 2ms+4ms
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548): nu.xom.XMLException: Could not find a suitable SAX2 parser
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    at nu.xom.Builder.findParser(Unknown Source)
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    at nu.xom.Builder.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    at nu.xom.Builder.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    at com.rkovalev.first.app.MainActivity$UpdateTask.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:294)
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    at com.rkovalev.first.app.MainActivity$UpdateTask.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:1)
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:618)
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548): Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Can't create default XMLReader; is system property org.xml.sax.driver set?
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(XMLReaderFactory.java:156)
11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548):    ... 14 more
```

Using code to experiment:

```
Builder parser = new Builder();
nu.xom.Document doc = parser.build("<greeting>Hello World!</greeting>", "http://www.example.org/");
```

So, I could not found a driver property in org.xml.sax namespace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790214/could-not-find-a-suitable-sax2-parser-when-i-try-parsing-xml-with-xom-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

This line of error log is related

11-28 22:00:11.325: W/System.err(26548): Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Can't create default XMLReader; is system property org.xml.sax.driver set?

This answer to this is here

[porting to Android: why am I getting "Can't create default XMLReader; is system property org.xml.sax.driver set?"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165477/porting-to-android-why-am-i-getting-cant-create-default-xmlreader-is-system)

Comment: You realy think that for it simply task I want to use SAX directly? I do not want